# Converting to timestamp

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have date that looks like this:
2021-03-15T04:22:59.000+0000

I need the date to be like this:
2021-03-15 04:22:59.000

I am trying to convert it but when I try the following I get null values or it gives an error:

```
to_timestamp_ntz(CREATEDDATE)
try_to_timestamp_ntz(CREATEDDATE)
to_timestamp_ntz(to_char(try_to_number(CREATEDDATE)))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So you need a timestamp with this format:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Watch out for the TRY_TO* since it handles error returning null when conversion cannot be performed.

Does this work:

```
Select TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(CREATEDDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as dt;
```